# Rails Apps - scaffold error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm having a rails app problem when executing the scaffold command in my command line. I used the `rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string` command that our teacher showed us today. His worked, but mine gets the following.

```
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:55:in `method_missing': undefined method `migration_error=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:66:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:65:in `each'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:65:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
```

There are more lines, but I would hope that you get the idea. If I need to post the rest, I will. Beyond that, if there is another question that has the answer to this, please point me in that direction. Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you done `rake db:migrate`?

Answer (score 0):

Try set up your database first by running this command

```
rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
```

or

```
rake db:reset
```